# Alamofire ssl wrong certificates Swift

Tags: swift, ssl, https, alamofire

I am trying to connect to https://wrong.host.badssl.com/ which uses an invalid certificate.

My code in Viewcontroller.swift:

```
let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["wrong.host.badssl.com:443": DisabledEvaluator()])
let session = Session(serverTrustManager: manager)
session.request("https://wrong.host.badssl.com").response { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

The response is:

```
[Request]: GET https://wrong.host.badssl.com
[Request Body]: 
None
[Response]: 
nil
[Response Body]: 
None
[Data]: None
[Network Duration]: None
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0s
[Result]: failure(Alamofire.AFError.sessionDeinitialized)
```

What am I doing wrong?

cheers Matthias

Answer (score 5):

If you see [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/AFError.swift) it clearly explains details of error `sessionDeinitialized`

> ```
> `Session` which issued the `Request` was deinitialized, most likely because its reference went out of scope.
> case sessionDeinitialized
> ```

Essentially, you need to keep a reference to your **Session** until your requests are complete, otherwise it will be deinitialized and cancel your requests.

You can do that through a **singleton** or by injecting the same instance into all users from somewhere that keeps the reference alive. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

```
if sessionObj == nil { //initialise session or whatever you are using if it is nil. }
```

I am using Session class of Alamofire here.